# List error application of TWC into a dataset

Tags: tivoli, tivoli-work-scheduler

Our Mainfarmes batch applications are scheduled in Tiwoli workload schedular(TWS), by the end of the batch some of the application are going in error.
I want to know is there any way I can get th list of the error application into a dataset.??

I know we can go to "QCP - Query the status of work in progress " option in TWS and get the list of error jobs on screen, but I want it in a dataset..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 options to implement this scenario:

- Create a PIF program, but that require programming skills. PIF are documented on the IBM Knowledge Center: [The program interface (PIF)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRULV_9.3.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.3/zos/src_pif/eqqn1proginterface.htm)
- Make a script using the [WAPL (Workload Automation Programming Language)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRULV_9.3.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.3/zos/src_wapl/eqqw1mst_welcome.html). This has been added with TWSs 9.3, for previous release it was called SOE (Scheduling Operational Environment) and was available as an external unsupported tool.

I suggest to see at WAPL, even if I don't have an example to make exactly what you are looking for, this should be possible, and much easier with WAPL then making a PIF program.